# Using @SpyBean with @Qualifier Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I have 2 `DataSource`s in my app.

So, to get the required `JdbcTemplate`, i use `@Qualifier`. But, when i do like below, the test runs... but stays waiting indefinitely, if there is any use of `JdbcTemplate` in the "Method Under Test".

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SampleDatabaseService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstDbJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate firstDbJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondDbJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate secondDbJdbcTemplate;

    @Cacheable("status")
    public Map<String, Device> readAllValidDeviceStatus() {
        Map<String, Device> allDeviceStatuses = new HashMap<>();
        //Stops at below line indefinitely if "SpyBean" is used
        List<StatusDetail> statusDetails = firstDbJdbcTemplate
               .query(SqlQueries.READ_DEVICE_STATUS, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(StatusDetail.class)); 

        statusDetails
               .stream()
               .filter(deviceStatus -> deviceStatus.getName() != "Some Invalid Name")
               .forEach(deviceStatus -> allDeviceStatuses
                  .put(deviceStatus.getName(), buildDevice(deviceStatus)));
        return allDeviceStatuses;
    }

/** More Stuff **/

}
```

and the **Test** :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
@Rollback
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SampleDatabaseServiceTest {

    @SpyBean
    @Qualifier("firstDbJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate firstDbJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SampleDatabaseService serviceUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void populateTables() {
        //Insert some Dummy Records in "InMemory HSQL DB" using firstDbJdbcTemplate
    }


    @Test
    public void testReadAllValidDeviceStatus() {
        // When
        Map<String, Device> allDeviceStatuses = serviceUnderTest.readAllValidDeviceStatus();

        // Then
        assertThat(allDeviceStatuses).isNotNull().isNotEmpty();
        // More checks
    }
    /* More Tests */
}
```

But, when i replace the `@SpyBean` with `@Autowired` in `Test`, it works fine.

Why is it so? Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use it in below format

```
  @MockBean(name = "firstDbJdbcTemplate") 
  private JdbcTemplate firstDbJdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: I ran into problems using `name=` and fixed I fixed it with an additional `@Qualified` annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `name` attribute of `SpyBean` annotation

```
@SpyBean(name = "firstDbJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate firstDbJdbcTemplate;
```